# kivymd object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to build a youtube video downloader but I'm stuck and getting an weird error, I don't how? I think my code looks ok but something is wrong, I'd try but i couldn't figure it out!

Please help me -

**error**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/main.py", line 84, in <module>
     Itube().run()
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/main.py", line 38, in __init__
     self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/uix/filemanager.py", line 403, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/theming.py", line 907, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/backgroundcolorbehavior.py", line 150, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/rohit/Desktop/Youtube_downloader/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.toast import toast
from youtube_dl import kv


Window.size = (450, 740)



class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SigninScreen(Screen):
    pass




sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='homescreen'))
sm.add_widget(SigninScreen(name='signinscreen'))





class Itube(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)

        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager = self.exit_manager, 
            self_path = self.select_path,
            preview = True,
        )


    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


    def file_manager_open(self):
        self.file_manager.show('/')  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True

    def select_path(self, path):
        '''It will be called when you click on the file name
        or the catalog selection button.

        :type path: str;
        :param path: path to the selected directory or file;
        '''

        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        '''Called when the user reaches the root of the directory tree.'''

        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device.'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True






if __name__ == "__main__":
    Itube().run()
```

**youtube_dl.py**

```
kv = """

ScreenManager:
    HomeScreen:
    SigninScreen:




<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'homescreen'



    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 20
        padding: 40


        MDTextFieldRound:
            hint_text: 'Url'
            multline: False
            normal_color: (1, 1, 1, 100)
            color_active: (232/255, 232/255, 232/255, 600)
            
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            adaptive_size: True
            spacing: 22
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .99}

            MDToolbar:
                title: 'FileManager'
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: None]]
                elevation: 10

            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Import from computer'
                icon: "folder"
                on_release: app.file_manager_open()
            
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Import from itube cloud'
    

    

        


<SigninScreen>:
    name: 'signinscreen'


"""
```

Or could you explain me the best way to structure **big kivymd application**.

Comment: Try to narrow down your question to a single thing at once, rather than your three unrelated questions plus very broad enquiry. Also, if you have an error then post the full thing - you've posted only a small amount of text that doesn't include any of the contextual information intended to help identify the problem. And finally, try to provide a more minimal example, it's very unlikely that most of the code here is necessary to provoke the error so it only makes it harder for readers to identify your issue.

Comment: As for the error, what it means is that you've passed an unexpected argument to a class, and that argument has eventually been passed up the superclass chain until it reaches `object.__init__`. You should therefore look for places where you pass arguments that don't exist, e.g. for the line `exit_manager = self.exit_manager,` is `exit_manager` actually a valid argument here?

Comment: If i remove `self.exit_manager`, I got `exit_manager = exit_manager, 
 NameError: name 'exit_manager' is not defined` error.

Comment: `exit_manager` was just an example, you need to look for the type of error I described.

Comment: Also the additional content of the error that you didn't paste here probably has some clues about what object instantiation is the problem.

Comment: `exit_manger` is a function and please refrersh again.

Comment: Have you read the traceback that you posted? It's telling you which object instantiation is the problem. One of the arguments in that instantiation probably doesn't exist.

Comment: what is instantiation? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please help me .....

Comment: The error probably indicates that the class instantiation starting with `self.file_manager = MDFileManager(` includes an argument that doesn't exist. I'm not familiar with this class and haven't checked the documentation, but I would look it up and check your arguments are all valid

Comment: See the [MDFileManager documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.0/components/file-manager/index.html#kivymd.uix.filemanager.MDFileManager). If you are passing any argument to `MDFileManager()` that is not in that list (or not legal for `FloatLayout` or `ThemableBehavior`), then you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

In self.file_manager you have written `self_path = self.select_path`. It will be `select_path = self.select_path`. Also, I don't know what's wrong with the `preview=True`, maybe a bug.
So your function will be:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
    self.manager_open = False
    self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
        exit_manager = self.exit_manager, 
        select_path = self.select_path,
    )
    self.file_manager.preview = True #Can try if it works
```